# I need to hide fields on certain accounts when a button is clicked

Tags: page-layout

I have a button I use to connect to an external application. When that button is clicked, the external application deletes data from certain fields on the account where the button has been clicked.

Users no longer want this functionality. Instead, they want the fields hidden from the page, but the data to be available for reports. I don't see how I can do this.

Is this at all possible? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a record type and a page layout without those fields.

When the button is clicked, update the recordtype of the account to the new record type which is associated with the page layout without those fields.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will the data for the record still be available for reporting purposes even after the record type has changed to not display said fields?

Comment: Yes it will be available in database so you can report on it.